# Cloud-init 18.5 module execution fails before creating the SSH keys

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, rhel, kvm, cloud-init

I am provisioning a virtual machine which executes the cloud init script on its first boot. I have a floating IP assigned to the VM and I can ping it, but can't ssh into it. I suspect that the cloud-init script execution has failed somewhere. Even if I pass userdata with password, the module may not execute the userdata script. How can I peek inside the VM to figure the root cause? This doesn't happen frequently.

```
Image: RHEL 8/9
Virtualization: KVM/Libvirt
Cloud-init version: 18.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I peek inside the VM to figure the root cause?

I would mount the VM's filesystem locally and inspect the log files (`/var/log/cloud-init.log`)

For example, you can mount a qcow2 image with [qemu-nbd](https://gist.github.com/shamil/62935d9b456a6f9877b5).

Comment: Will see if that is possible. Thank you